# i am using google chart api i want to set the labels for x axis

Tags: c#

i am using google chart api i want to set the labels for x axis but problem is that tese labels are overlapping
my source code is this..........

```
        BarChart barchart1 = new BarChart(350, 200, BarChartOrientation.Vertical, BarChartStyle.Stacked);
        barchart1.SetTitle("Bedrooms distribution of " + City);
        barchart1.SetData(data);
        barchart1.AddAxis(new ChartAxis(ChartAxisType.Bottom));
        barchart1.AddAxis(new ChartAxis(ChartAxisType.Left));

        ChartAxis chx1 = new ChartAxis(ChartAxisType.Bottom);
        for (int s = 0; s < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; s++)
        {
            ChartAxisLabel chl1 = new ChartAxisLabel(labels[s]);


            chx1.AddLabel(chl1);

        }
        barchart1.AddAxis(chx1);
        barchart1.SetBarWidth(20);

     //   barchart1.SetLegend(labels);

        barchart1.SetDatasetColors(new string[] { "FF0000", "FFFF00", "CCCCCC", "EFEFEF", "FFFF00", "9900FF", "66FF99", "00AA00", "224499", "00CC33" });


        Image1.ImageUrl = barchart1.GetUrl();


            Image1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you need just one simple chart (with variable values) You can generate the URL for that chart (you will have to understand the basic chart API). Then use the System.Net.webclient to download the chart

```
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        WebClient client = new WebClient ();

        Stream data = client.OpenRead (args[0]);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        data.Close ();
        reader.Close ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# wrapper for the Google Chart API - http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/